# Windows 2008 R2 App Locker define times program is opened

Tags: windows-server-2008, group-policy

I am testing AppLock currently. I have create a GroupPolicyObject and added a Executable rule. The .exe I am referencing for this test is Calc.exe . How would I define that I only want want two instances of calc.exe opened and if a user in the group opens a 3rd one, it denies them. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

I do not believe that is possible with Applocker. You can restrict which users can run an application, but I don't think you can limit concurrent usage otherwise, which is what you are asking.

If you're looking for a good third-party product that will do that, though, check out [Asset Manager](http://www.quest.com/asset-manager/) from Quest Software.